# WinAPI работа с данными

Tags: данные

данные

```
#include<iostream>
#include<windows.h>
using namespace std;

bool Keysearch = false;


int main()
{
    
        cout << "Error Path!" << endl;
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }

    cout << "Enter your keyname to search > ";
    cin >> Name;
    cout << endl;
    string HalfKey = "";
    FindKeys(PathForKey, HalfKey, Name, Keysearch);
    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void FindKeys(HKEY Root, string SubKeyss, TCHAR* Search, bool Keysearch)
{
    HKEY SubKeys2;
    DWORD CountKey, BufferSize;
    TCHAR BufName[1024];
    
    DWORD Output = RegOpenKeyEx(Root, SubKeys3, NULL, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &SubKeys2);
  
    RegQueryInfoKey(SubKeys2, NULL, NULL, NULL, &CountKey, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    if (!CountKey)
        return;
    for (DWORD i = 0; i < CountKey && !Keysearch; i++)
    {
        BufferSize = sizeof(BufSubKey);
        RegEnumKeyEx(SubKeys2, i, BufSubKey, &BufferSize, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых надо убрать `Keysearch`, т.к. его проверка позволит найти только первый ключ чье имя содержит строку. Во-вторых не следует выводить все ключи в которых искали, это замусорит вывод. В-третьих следует проверять ошибки возвращаемые функциями открытия ключей реестра - если запускать без прав администратора ко многим ключам нет доступа. Такая функция FindKeys, если запускать программу с правами администратора, находит подключ `Fonts`:

```
void FindKeys(HKEY Root, string SubKeyss, TCHAR* Search, bool Keysearch)
{
  HKEY SubKeys2;
  DWORD CountKey;
  char BufSubKey[1024];
  const char* SubKeys3 = SubKeyss.c_str();

  DWORD errCode = RegOpenKeyEx(Root, SubKeys3, NULL, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &SubKeys2);
  if (errCode != ERROR_SUCCESS)
  {
    //cout << "Error opening key " << SubKeys3 << ", error " << errCode << endl;
    return;
  }
  errCode = RegQueryInfoKey(SubKeys2, NULL, NULL, NULL, &CountKey, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
  if (errCode != ERROR_SUCCESS)
  {
    //cout << "Error querying key " << SubKeys3 << ", error " << errCode << endl;
    return;
  }

  for (DWORD i = 0; i < CountKey; i++)
  {
    DWORD BufferSize = sizeof(BufSubKey);
    RegEnumKeyEx(SubKeys2, i, BufSubKey, &BufferSize, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    string keyName = BufSubKey;
    keyName = SubKeyss + BufSubKey + "\\";
    if (!strcmp(BufSubKey, Search))
    {
      cout << keyName << endl;
    }

    FindKeys(Root, keyName, Search, Keysearch);
  }
}
```